# Ionic v5/Angular 8: HttpClient.get().subscribe() returns TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, httpclient

HttpClient.get('...').subscribe((data:any) => { console.log(data) }))
cause error and I am not able to find where the problem is. Please, do you have any idea what is going wrong? I am Angular beginner.

I get propably valid Observe object to the this.httpObserve
subscribe on observe object cause this error.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined (core.js:9110)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http.js:1246)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:46)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:36)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:3)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (mergeMap.js:21)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:23)
    at FilterOperator.call (filter.js:13)
```

---

```
----------- apicall.service.ts ----------------
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApicallService {
  httpObserve;
  httpHandler : HttpHandler;

  constructor() { }

  http = new HttpClient(this.httpHandler);

  public getData(val) : any {
    // test url
    this.httpObserve = this.http.get('https://www.seznam.cz');
    return this.httpObserve;
  }
}
```

---

```
----------- myapi.component.ts -------------------
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApicallService } from '../apicall.service';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-myapi',
  templateUrl: './myapi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myapi.component.scss'],
})

export class MyapiComponent implements OnInit {
  result : any;
  httpObserve;

  constructor() {}

  apicall = new ApicallService();

  ngOnInit(){}

  get(val): void {
    this.httpObserve = this.apicall.getData(val);
    this.httpObserve.subscribe((data:any) => { console.log(data) });
  }
}
```

---

```
page.ts

myapi = new MyapiComponent();
this.res = this.myapi.get(val);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you initiate without any value inside `httpHandler`.

```
http = new HttpClient(this.httpHandler); // <-- his.httpHandler is null
```

If there is no need for `httpHandler`,

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

// remove httpHandler : HttpHandler;
// remove  http = new HttpClient(this.httpHandler);
```

Comment: Yes, because I am not able to find what argument should be there:( What change I should make please?

Comment: If you don't use HttpHandler, then inject the httpClient into your constructor to use it

Comment: BUT, the better thing to do right now, is to learn the [Angular Basic](https://angular.io/tutorial)

Comment: Yes, thank you for information. Yes, I am new in Angular and I have to get basics.